# C/C++ .exe can run on eclipse

Tags: java, android, c++, eclipse

I wrote the code in VS C++ and I have to run it on android ,I know about JNI approach but what I want to know is that , if i make .exe of that code in c/c++ VS then i call it in java android , then it will work or I can do it or not

Answer (score 0):

`.exe` is a Windows executable binary (program). It is not only compiled for the wrong platform (Windows), but also for the wrong cpu architecture.

You will have to separately cross-compile from the same code to support Android.

Comment: so you want to say that there is no good option then JNI approach

Comment: Use the JNI approach.

Answer (score 0):

you can directly run exe by java

```
try {
    Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();
    Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c start "+file.getAbsolutePath());
    p.waitFor();
} catch (IOException e1) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e1.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: for android ? or only for java ?

Answer (score 0):

try to compile your c++ code with necessitas [ http://necessitas.kde.org/] it will generate a Apk file for you and you can easily run that on Android :)

Comment: you can compile VS C++ code on qt as well as on necessitas but you cant generate APK file direct from VS.